# VBA: Paste ceases to work (suddenly) in specific macro

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm a very new, self-taught programmer, so please keep this in mind in your responses. I have extensively searched this and other forums and can't seem to find a similar question.

The following code has been working for weeks and has not been changed. (My macro includes more variables and code, but I know from taking it apart that those pieces work, so I've left them out for clarity). From what I can tell the **PasteSpecial** function is specifically not working.

```
Dim StimSheet As String

ActiveCell.Rows("1:290").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
'Copies the data for the current stimulus
StimSheet = Application.InputBox("Enter the name of the stimulus")
'asks name of the stimulus

Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = StimSheet
'adds new sheet at the end and names whatever you input as stimulus name

Sheets(StimSheet).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'pastes data into new sheet
```

At this point there is no error, the macro simply stops after copying and creating the new sheet.

Here's what I know / have tried:

1. The macro is successfully making and naming the new sheet and copying the selection to the clipboard, because I can manually paste it after running the macro. It seems to be getting stuck at the paste piece.
2. **Other macros that use the exact same format of copy / paste special are still working correctly**.
3. Another forum with a similar program suggested typing "Application.EnableEvents=True" into the immediate window. This did not change anything.
4. **This macro has worked for several weeks with no errors.** I have made new macros using previously saved code in case something inadvertently was changed in the current one, but this did not work either.
5. **The paste option *will* work one time on a new file and then ceases to work again.**

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Does it work on another workstation?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have immediate access to another work station, but have passed onto a colleague in another location to try. I'll update with that information when I hear back.

Comment: @MatthewD I am working on a Mac using Office 2011; sent to a colleague using a Mac with Office 2011 and the code works, so must be specific to my workstation. I have since tried writing new code and trying it on a different set of files and am still having this issue. Have restarted my computer, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the problem is that you don't have much control over which workbook and worksheet this code applies to. It's better to avoid `ActiveSheet`, `Select`, and `Sheet` with no parent as much as you can.

If you only need to copy the values of cells without any formatting, then `Paste` isn't needed either.

Try changing your code to the following and see if you have any better luck:

```
Const BOOK_NAME As String = "Book1.xlsm" 'change this to your workbook name
Const SOURCE_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1" 'change this to your sheet name
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim newSheetName As String
Dim validName As Boolean
Dim rng As Range

' Set the book, sheet and range objects
Set wb = Workbooks(BOOK_NAME)
Set sourceSheet = wb.Worksheets(SOURCE_SHEET_NAME)
Set newSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))

' Acquire the new sheet name and check it's valid.
Do
    newSheetName = InputBox("Enter the name of the stimulus")
    On Error Resume Next
    newSheet.Name = newSheetName
    validName = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not validName Then MsgBox "Sheet name isn't valid. Try again."
Loop Until validName

' Write the values into the new sheet
Set rng = sourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(290, sourceSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
newSheet.Range(rng.Address).value = rng.Value2
```

Comment: Are you working on two different workbooks by any chance and the source sheet has a generic name like "Sheet1"? That would explain this and your 1004 errors.

Comment: I just deleted my previous comment, as that is now working -- must have been an error on my part when I inserted your code. It is working smoothly now. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I moved this line:

```
StimSheet = Application.InputBox("Enter the name of the stimulus")
```

to the top of the method and it seems to work reliably. I wish I could tell you exactly why, but at least you can proceed. Perhaps it has something to do with the focus changing.

Also, when it failed for me (Office 2013) I got the following error:

*Run-time error 1004:
Application-defined or object-defined error.*

When the Sub was in a Sheet code behind, and this:

*Run-time error '1004'
PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.*

When pasted in a Module.

Comment: Thanks @Chaz. I was just about to post an update saying that I had tried re-writing / using a different sample document and everything was working until I added that line in. I'll try moving that around and checking for any updates to Excel that may have been installed.

Comment: "Perhaps it has something to do with the focus changing". Yes. @katunruh, please see my response as your code is unsafe. If you have more than one application open, more than one workbook open or a switch of sheets then your code will always throw a 1004 error.